# Looking for specific character in capture group

Tags: php, preg-replace, pcre

I need to replace all double quotes in any (variable) given string.

For example:

```
$text = 'data-caption="hello"world">';
$pattern = '/data-caption="[[\s\S]*?"|(")]*?">/';
$output = preg_replace($pattern, '&quot;', $text);
```

should result in:

```
"hello&quot;world"
```

(The above pattern is my attempt at getting it to work)

The problem is that I don't now in advance if and how many double quotes are going to be in the string.

How can i replace the `"` with `quot;` ?

Comment: Do you want to match just a very specific string or is it part of a longer HTML and the attribute can be preceded / followed with other attributes?

Comment: this is just an extract of a larger html structure. the `data-caption="` and `">` limiters can in appear multiple times.

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/pbMGbc

Comment: It looks like a promising start, but it didn't yet work for me. Maybe it's because of a different string composition? Here's a "real" string from my files: `data-caption="&lt;element attribute1="wert" attribute2="wert"&gt;Name&lt;/element&gt;">`

Comment: So, how can you describe the trailing delimiter? `data-caption="` is the leading one. How do you know where to stop?

Comment: The part of the string, in which I need to replace the characters is always enclosed in:
- beginning: `data-caption="`
- end: `">`

Comment: Then https://ideone.com/pbMGbc must work for you.

Comment: My bad, I didn't see that you updated the pattern. Now it is working as intended. If you post it as an answer I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match strings between `data-caption="` and `">` and then replace all `"` inside that match with `&quot;` using a mere `str_replace`:

```
$text = 'data-caption="&lt;element attribute1="wert" attribute2="wert"&gt;Name&lt;/element&gt;">';
$pattern = '/data-caption="\K.*?(?=">)/';
$output = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($m) {
        return str_replace('"', '&quot;', $m[0]);
    }, $text);
print_r($output);
// => data-caption="&lt;element attribute1=&quot;wert&quot; attribute2=&quot;wert&quot;&gt;Name&lt;/element&gt;">
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/pbMGbc)

**Details**

- `data-caption="` - starting delimiter
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=">)` - a positive lookahead that requires the `">` substring immediately to the right of the current location.

The match is passed to the anonymous function inside `preg_replace_callback` (accessible via `$m[0]`) and that is where it is possible to replace all `"` symbols in a convenient way.